# Searchkick where hash optional params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

How to write this code with Ruby and Searchkick gem.

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#queries

```
# Works
@espacos = User.search where: {
  gender: params[:gender], # options: :male and :female
  other_param: param,
  other_param: param
}

# How do search all if the parameter is not informed?
@espacos = User.search where: {
  if not nil params[:gender]
    gender: params[:gender],
  end
  other_param: param,
  other_param: param
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
options = {
  other_param: other_param
  yet_another: yet_another
}

options[:gender] = params[:gender] if params[:gender].present?
```

Editing to satisfy request below

```
[:gender, :sex, :colour].each do |s|
  options[:s] = params[:s] if params[:s].present?
end
```

Comment: Nice! How to do this with multiple parameters without repeating many options lines?

Comment: Thx! fix: options[s] = params[s] if params[s].present?